# return a list from different rows into a single field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
|animal | name   |
|----------------|
|dog    | Fido   |
|----------------|
|dog    | Spot   |
|----------------|
|dog    | Lassie |
|----------------|
|cat    | Sue    |
|----------------|
|cat    | Ace    |
|----------------|
|cat    | Felix  |
|----------------|
|pig    | Porky  |
|----------------|
|pig    | Arnold |
|----------------|
```

I need an SQL query that will return the following

```
dog | Fido, Spot, Lassie
cat | Sue, Ace, Felix
pig | Porky, Arnold
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select animal, group_concat(name)
from your_table
group by animal
```

Comment: group_concat? when did they come up with that? Thanks.

Comment: very cool.  here's the manual page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat